# Set 256 color prompt in zsh/kitty/tmux

Tags: zsh, tmux, kitty

This problem is only for the Kitty terminal (works in alacritty, Hyper; problem exists both on macos and arch linux)

currently set my terminal with

```
PS1='%B%F{magenta}%3~ ${vim_mode}%f%b '
```

this sets the prompt to magenta in both the base terminal and tmux.  however, if I use a 256 color number like 170 in place of magenta, the prompt color gets set in the base terminal but not tmux.  is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What's your `$TERM` inside `tmux` set to?

Comment: $TERM is tmux.  I have

Comment: Try `TERM=xterm-256color`

Comment: That Didn't work